# CSV file content is being loaded with "quotes"

Tags: python, csv, file

I need help to write and recover data from a csv file.

My parameter `game` is a tuple of 2 elements. Here's an example:

```
(((4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)), [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I need two functions, one to save the game an another one to recover it. This is what I've at the moment:

To save the game:

```
def save_game(game):
    with open ('file.csv', 'w') as f:
        csv_file = csv.writer(f)
        csv_file.writerow(game)
```

To recover the game:

```
def recover_game():
    with open ('file.csv', 'r') as f:
        csv_file = csv.reader(f)
        for line in csv_file:
            game = line[0], line[1]
            return game
```

When recovering the game, however, I'm getting something like this:

```
('((4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3))', '[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]')
```

Is there any way to remove the quotes, so I can get a similar tuple like the one passed to my `game` parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: The module  `csv` translates everything that is not a string (such as a tuple) into a string representation before writing it. But you want to store tuples, not string representations. So a CSV is a poor choice for persisting your data. Take a look at the `pickle` module.

Comment: What do you want your data to look like _as a CSV file_? It can't look exactly like your original tuples, but if you wanted each tuple to correspond with a line in the file (for example), that's doable.

Comment: Having it be just one line doesn't really make sense. One line per tuple would be a better choice.

Comment: But if I want to do it with the CSV module, Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BoarGules pointed out, you should probably use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) in this case. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pickle


def save_game(game, out_pathname="./game.pkl"):
    with open(out_pathname, "wb") as out_file:
        pickle.dump(game, out_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


def recover_game(in_pathname="./game.pkl"):
    with open(in_pathname, "rb") as in_file:
        return pickle.load(in_file)
```

One of the nice things about this method is that it works with any picklable object, so even if you later decide to change the internal details of your `game` object, the two functions above should still work.